# ASP.NET Core - Client-side AJAX not working for IE11/Edge

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, cors, microsoft-edge

I've literally been researching for 5+ days for a problem that only exists within IE and Edge (works in Chrome, FireFox, etc). I've gone through pretty much all of the links and tried nearly everything, but it seems that a lot of the content/answers out there from older posts are very outdated.

**Background:** I created an ASP.NET Core web service - it is running on some port on localhost. Ideally, I'd have my users open an locally-residing html document (meaning living on their local filesystem and not hosted on a server) that pings the web service through AJAX (that returns some JSON) - allowing for that content from the web service to be displayed in the html document. It literally works in all browsers except IE and Edge (I'm using IE11).

**Here is my Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    ...
    services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("ContentServices", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
    }));
    services.AddMvc();
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    app.UseCors("ContentServices");
    ...
}
```

**Here is my SearchController.cs:**

```
[EnableCors("ContentServices")]
public SearchResponse Query(string index, string input, SearchType searchType, int page = 0, int pageSize = 20)
{
    SearchResponse sr = new SearchResponse;
    ...
    return sr;     
}
```

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
function WebService(url, successMsg, errorMsg) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: searchDestinationUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (results) {
            return results;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(error + " - " + errorMsg);
        }
    });
}

function RunGeneralSearch(input, options) {
        var search = WebService("search/query?index=" + index + "&input=" + input + "&page=" + options.content.pageIndex + "&pageSize=" + options.content.pageSize, "", "Search failed.")
            .then(function (response) {
                var searchResults = [];
                searchResults.content = [];
                searchResults.contentTotal = response.total;
                searchResults.clientPaging = false;

                var results = response.results;
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    var Search = MadCap.CreateNamespace("WebHelp.Search");

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        var result = results[i];
                        var rank = result["rank"];
                        var title = result["title"];
                        var link = result["link"];
                        var linkUrl = GetLinkUrl(link);
                        var abstractText = result["abstractText"];

                        var searchResult = new Search.SearchResult(rank, title, linkUrl.FullPath, unescape(abstractText));
                        searchResults.content.push(searchResult);
                    }
                }

                return searchResults;
            });

        return search;
    };
}
```

**Things I've tried:**

1. Using `$.support.cors = true` will work for IE with the exception
   that it will prompt an warning for every ping that is made to the
   web service regarding security: `"This page is accessing information that is not under its control. This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue?"` This is absolutely annoying, and I will not have my customers modify their security settings for this. This also does not work for Edge at all.
2. Changing the `crossDomain` attribute in the AJAX call to `false` - behavior is the same as the above except that it will not work for all other browsers now.
3. I've read a lot about using the `dataType: 'jsonp'` - but as far as I know, it's deprecated and only supports GET requests. So I did not try this and want to stay away from it.
4. I've also read that because I'm trying to access the web service through a locally-residing unhosted file (i.e. url is `file://` instead of `http://`) that it is technically not supported as an origin - so allowing any origin wouldn't help in this case. I'm not sure how true this is or even how to test this. Regardless, I have not tried serving the html file over localhost because I do not want to require my clients to have to do this ***just for IE/Edge*** when it works completely fine with all other browsers.
5. I've tried using an `XMLHttpRequest` instead of and AJAX call. It requires me to then do `JSON.parse(result);` but seems to work perfectly for all browsers including IE except Edge...

I understand to some extent about CORS and the limitations of the same origin policy, but I absolutely don't understand what the difference is between Microsoft browsers and the rest.

**Please help!**